# Convert string to valid path for bash command

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a file path in `ruby` I want to pass it to a bash command but because the file path contains special characters like space this command not executes.

I want to convert something like `'foo/bar/file name with (special) characters.zip'`
to `'foo/bar/file\ name\ with\ \(special\)\ characters.zip'`

How to convert it in ruby ?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Please show us the code you have troubles with.

Comment: Use `Kernel.spawn` to bypass the shell instead of trying to build a string that the shell can parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Shellwords#shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape).

```rb
require 'shellwords'

fname = 'foo/bar/file name with (special) characters.zip'

fname.shellescape  # => "foo/bar/file\\ name\\ with\\ \\(special\\)\\ characters.zip"
```